# Numpy Python Parallelization Scaling Identically to Serial Computation

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I am trying to show some sort of improvement by parallelizing a toy piece of code in Python before I attempt to parallelize my main program. The approach I have decided to take is to perform four matrix inversions in parallel, and then perform the same matrix inversion one time and multiply by four to get an estimate for how long the problem would take to finish in serial. I understand there will be some constant overhead with parallelizing, but as a first order approximation this should be fine for my purposes.

The issue I am running into is that the parallel computations are running slowly enough that it appears each of the four inversions are just being executed serially.

I have included my code to compare with. Note that I have tried two different approaches, one using just multiprocessing, and one using joblib (commented out) and both give me comparable runtimes. mp.cpu_count returns 20 CPUs available, so I am confident that this is not an issue with my computer.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = np.random.random((10000,10000))
    tA = [A,A,A,A]
    print mp.cpu_count()

    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    t = time.time()
    # results = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(np.linalg.inv)(i) for i in tA)
    results = pool.map(np.linalg.inv, tA)
    print time.time() - t

    t = time.time()
    temp = np.linalg.inv(A)
    print (time.time()-t)*len(tA)
```

For reference, here is the output when I run this code

```
20
62.151000229
52.516007477
```

Comment: Opening a new process adds a lot of overhead to your program, since you're only doing matrix inversion, the time you saved from running in parallel is much less than the overhead added.

Comment: That would be a constant overhead. I see a similar disparity when I just try to invert 5000x5000.

Comment: @Ding, that's not it, on at least 2 counts:  (1) his serial timing shows the inversion taking about 13 seconds - that's an eternity compared to the time needed to create a new process; and, (2) `mp.Pool(4)` creates the 4 processes, and that line isn't in the part being timed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your cpu-load when not using process-based parallelization. I would not be surprised to see, that your *non-parallel*-code is heavily using threads (transparently). Going by cpu-load it's not a proof, but a strong indication.

If your system is set up correctly, [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)/[LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) will be used ([dgetrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgetrf.f.html)) and most implementations should be highly threaded (within C or Fortran code)! If that's true, that's obviously a problem in your benchmark.

Comment: It appears (just going from task manager) that my processor utilization climbs relatively high across all of my CPUs when running even just a single matrix inversion. I'm running the Anaconda distribution of Python in order to run SciPy on Windows, so is the answer just that what I was trying to benchmark was itself already generating a bunch of threads that were distributed?

Comment: I think so. Maybe it's using Intels MKL (default in anaconda, maybe). Maybe some other BLAS/LAPACK (but some BLAS/LAPACK is shipped or anaconda would be kind of useless).

Comment: Huh. Good to know. I'll try to generate some other sort of method for verifying that it's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good luck. Everything within numpy/scipy heavily based on matrix-matrix or matrix-vector calculations (and maybe vector-vector and some more) will be parallelized.

Comment: That appears to have been the issue. I wrote a function that iterated through a vector and returned the square root of each element of the vector. Running this four times in parallel similar to my original code with several million elements took about 15 seconds for all to finish. Running it once and then multiplying the final time by 4 gives me 50 seconds, so slightly less than 4 times the parallel computation, as I expected.

Comment: And for fun you might try ```numpy.sqrt(my_vector)```.